# Никому неприятно будет знать, что ...

Tags: лексика

Не первый раз встречаю в текстах конструкцию типа "Никому неприятно будет знать, что ...". Какого типа эта ошибка? На мой взгляд, должно быть "никому не будет приятно знать, что ..." или "любому неприятно будет знать, что...".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4):

К сожалению, несмотря на многочисленные рекомендации, бывает трудно однозначно классифицировать ошибку: грамматическая? речевая? Сначала уверенно начала писать - конечно. грамматическая. Явно неправильно построено предложение. Вы поменяли порядок слов - ошибка исчезла. Ошибка в порядке слов - грамматическая. Но во втором исправленном варианте порядок слов тот же, местоимение другое. А неправильный выбор слова (местоимения) - речевая ошибка. Можно и по-другому исправить: никому не понравится... Этот глагол совершенного вида. Знать - несовершенного. Имеет сложную форму будущего времени. На мой взгляд, это одна из причин ошибок.

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже ломала голову: речевая или грамматическая? Получается, ответ зависит от того, как исправлена эта ошибка. Я искала еще какие-нибудь указания на правила построения предложения, в котором субъект "отрицательный". У нас ведь отрицание должно быть двойным, а не как у англичан (nobody knows - никто не знает). Вот только где должно быть второе отрицание? Понятно, что "отрицаться" должен предикат. Но есть ли где-нибудь такое правило?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка грамматическая.
Возможность правки путем замены на другое местоимение (даже почти синонимичное, если позволено будет так выразиться) не означает грамматической правильности исходного варианта. Тут очевидная грамматическая несочетаемость, а не только - и даже не столько - лексическая.
Конкретно здесь - неверное употребление двойного отрицания. Речь о том, что употребление отрицательного местоимения (и других подобных слов с "ни") в русском (в отличие от английского) возможно только в сочетании с отрицанием глагола. А в исходном варианте его нет. Кстати, это означает, что предлагаемая правка "перестановкой слов" на самом деле  гороздо более существенна грамматически.

Comment: Продолжение комментария к ответу @__inna__ 18 Июн 23:17 

Тем не менее я говов посмотреть на все это как на условный пример. Так вот, во фразе на естественном языке ошибок нет. Никаких. При переводе на искуственный язык возникла проблема перевода. Если это и ошибка, то синтаксическая. В естественном языке союз И связывает множества (клиентов), в искусственном - условия на этих клиентов. Типичная проблема синтаксиса искусственного языка.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы так проанализировала:

*Никому неприятно будет знать, что...*
Если *никому неприятно будет...* -- значит, будет всем приятно. Минус на минус -- плюс. Ошибка логическая по сути. Логические ошибки относятся к грамматическим?

Кстати, по-моему, нельзя сказать, что изменился порядок слов. Просто переставили частицу НЕ.

Больше всего понравился вариант *Любому неприятно будет знать, что...* Возможно, потому что здесь всего одно отрицание.

Comment: Логические ошибки не относятся к "компетенции" русского языка, это область логики, ну может отчасти - риторики. Уже поэтому ошибку нельзя назвать ни грамматической, ни стилистической.    
Но, по счастью, её, логической ошибки, тут нет. А если и есть, то не в ней дело. Перво-наперво тут дело в грамматике. Престановка слова НЕ, как вы, надеюсь, понимаете, не просто инверсия, она влечет изменение грамматической структуры.

Comment: Я бы так не отбрасывала логику от "компетенции" русского языка. Ведь при синтаксически и грамматически правильном построении предложения возможны алогизмы.

Comment: А может, это и вовсе не ошибка: "Никому неприятно будет знать, что..."? Поскольку русскому языку свойственно двойное отрицание... 

Вспомнила пример несовпадения логики русского языка и языка программирования. Один бизнесмен дал задание найти в базе данных клиентов в Техасе и в Теннесси. Но результат был нулевым. Все потому, что компьютеру надо было сказать найти клиентов в Техасе ИЛИ в Теннесси. Так как нет таких клиентов: одновременно и в Техасе, и в Теннесси.

Comment: То есть понятие логичности (выражения, высказывания) по сути относительное. В языках программирования -- свои особенности и законы логики, в английском языке -- свои, точно так же и в русском.

Comment: Всё это очеь хорошо, но, простите, а какой раздел русского языка как научной дисциплины изычает логику? Если алогизмы возникают вследствие грмаатической или какой-то другой нелогической ошибки, то она, эта ошибка, и определяет систематику ошибочности. Если же собственно языковых (не логических) ошибок там нет, то при чем тут язык?

Comment: Я совсем не специалист, возножно просто не понимаю термина "логическая ошибка" применительно к языку, но вообще-то логической ошибкой называют ошибочность вывода. Например такого: "Все кошки смертны. Сократ смертен. Следовательно, Сократ - кошка". Русский язык тут предельно правилен, разве что к пунктуации можно придраться при большом желании. Но в ответе - чушь.

Comment: В отношении вашего примера.  
Как реальный пример рассматривать не меогу. Во-первых, это не логика языка, а логика предикатов, раздел математической логики. Во-вторых, актуальность его - годы 80-е, тогда с подобным и сам сталкивался, но, конечно, не в такой абсурдной постановке. Сейчас запросы "для чайников" пишутся на языке, близком к естественному.

Comment: Комментарий к комментарию.Конечно, логику изучает наука логика. Но при построении текста (имеет отношение к языку!) часто законы логики нарушаются. Возникают логические ошибки. Например,  предмет мысли на протяжении всего высказывания должен оставаться неизменным.
Типичная ошибка— подмена тезиса, когда говорящий незаметно для себя изменяет тему и начинает говорить о другом.
    Не могут быть одновременно истинными противоположные высказывания об одном и том же.  
Типичная ошибка — расположение в одном тексте предложений, в которых утверждается совершенно противоположное.
Есть и другие ошибки.

Comment: ...какой раздел русского языка как научной дисциплины изычает логику?

По-моему, этот раздел называется логика речи. Именно речи, а не языка. Ведь язык -- это система ресурсов, средств (знаков, слов и других единиц речи) и правил их употребления. А речь -- воплощение этих ресурсов в жизни в конкретном времени и конкретным субъектом. Тем не менее и язык, и речь - понятия тесно взаимодействующие. То, как мы говорим, влияет на эволюцию языка как систему правил. И наша речь должна подчиняться законам языка. А также, с другой стороны, -- законам логики.

Answer (score 0):

Друзья мои! Ошибка здесь - орфографическая... Никому не приятно будет знать, что ни двойное отрицание, ни мудреные способы исправления, ни переводы на английский для данного случая совершенно не существенны... Так же, как в предложении с предикатом настоящего времени: "Такое никому не приятно видеть в написанном виде." А также в случае, если сказуемое не составное, а простое: "Просто никому не приятно". Вот и вся премудрость... Будьте проще - и к вам потянутся люди!

Comment: *Никому не приятно будет знать,* - Вы считаете это эта конструкция грамматически правильная? Докажите. Я этого не вижу.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка грамматическая. Если грамматика требует определенного порядка слов ("не" должно стоять непосредственно перед словом, к которому оно относится), то нарушение этого порядка - нарушение грамматики, а не орфографии. 
Аналогично, если **грамматика** требует конкретного местоимения, то использование "не того" местоимения - это тоже нарушение грамматики.

Хотя в чем-то я могу согласиться и с Ларf. Иногда бывает сложно классифицировать ошибку, если её можно исправить разными способами. Но не в данном случае. Здесь все равно ошибка грамматическая, как ни правь.